# angular json array - duplicate table creation problem

Tags: json, angular

I have a code structure as below, the data comes as an array, but more than one table is formed. I think I'm doing something wrong on the HTML side. Is there any way to fix this

When I try to import the data in the Material Demands Details from the json into a table, it creates more than one table

```
      <li *ngFor="let item of materialsDetails" >
        <ol *ngFor="let subItem of item.materialDemandDetails">
          <table mat-table [dataSource]="materialsDetails" class="mat-elevation-z8">
           
            <!-- Id Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{subItem.id}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
          </table>
        </ol>
      </li>
```

I've been trying for hours but I couldn't find where I made a mistake on the html side.

i have json data like below and i want to get array inside a nested data and pass it to table

**Json**

```
[
 {
 "description": "Ram .",
 "createdUserId": "12345",
 "createdUserName": "demo user",
 "status": "idle",
 "companyId": 2,
 "materialDemandId": 0,
 "materialDemandDetails": [
     {
         "stockName": "Ram 12 gb products",
         "totalDemand": 2,
         "materialDemandId": 1,
         "productId": 2,
         "id": 1,
         "createdDate": "2022-02-08T14:29:11.1763481",
         "updatedDate": "2022-02-08T11:28:42.409",
         "totalCount": 0,
         "companyId": 0
     },
     {
         "stockName": "Ram 12 gb",
         "totalDemand": 2,
         "materialDemandId": 1,
         "productId": 1,
         "id": 3,
         "createdDate": "2022-02-08T14:32:09.7305862",
         "updatedDate": "2022-02-08T11:28:42.409",
         "totalCount": 0,
         "companyId": 0
     }
 ],
 "id": 1,
 "createdDate": "2022-02-08T14:28:33.0658772",
 "updatedDate": "2022-02-08T11:27:46.939",
 "totalCount": 0
 }
]
```

[image: duplicate table image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="materialDemandDetailsNew" class="mat-elevation-z8">
   
    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{subItem.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

And in the component map the whole list into a new variable which you can use in the table

```
var materialDemandDetailsNew = [];
materialsDetails.forEach(item => item.materialDemandDetails.forEach(detail => materialDemandDetailsNew.push(detail)))
```

Hope I got the question right